# get around the if not empty when using date eg: 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment I am checking `if(!is_null($foo))` although this is breaking when the mysql column is a date and defaults to 0000-00-00.

Is there any way to get around this problem without adding `!= "0000-00-00"`

Comment: Don't allow `0000-00-00` dates into your database to begin with. Otherwise, no.

Comment: The date is optional so that is not possible

Comment: Not in PHP. I think, you shouldnt default this column to "0000-00-00", but to `NULL`. If this is, for any reason, not possible, you have to deal with this special value.

Comment: @DerVO - That is a brilliant idea and will fix all my issues. Add this as an answer and I shall accept.

Comment: @DerVo sorry just read your comment after i left my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your table definition for the date column

```
`date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

I always suggest to allow `NULL` for optional fields and to soundly distinguish between valid values like `0` and empty strings on the one hand and `NULL` (=not stated) on the other hand.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to solve it in code, solve it in the data.

You should let MySQL default to `NULL` not `0000-00-00`

Answer (score 2):

For date fields you can use [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). This function returns `false` if the `date` passed to it is not a `date`. 
I am not sure about your specific needs as there is very little info in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use something like this:

```
if(!(int)$foo)
{
    echo ' this is either a default value or a NULL';
}
```